# AngularJs POST request for json not working

Tags: angularjs, json, codeigniter, http-post

Hi i tried POST json data in two ways its response in null

```js
    var jsonData = $scope.addedCat; 
    console.log(jsonData);
    var request = $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:base_url+"Category_controller/json_test",
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
        dataType: "application/json"
    });
    request.success(
    function(response){
         console.log(response);
    });
```

```js
var cat_j = $scope.addedCat;
var data = $.param({ json:JSON.stringify(cat_j)});
$http.post(base_url+"Category_controller/json_test/",data).success(function(data, status) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(status);
    })
```

How we decode the json data in php.
    I tried like this in Codeignitor framework.

```
    $cjson = $this->input->post('jsonData');
    $cat_json = json_decode($cjson);
    echo json_encode($cat_json);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superglobal $_post only support `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data-encoded`.

For `application/json` you should use `php://input` which can give you the raw bytes of the data. Here is a sample code of how to get the input data:

// get the raw POST data

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

// this returns null if not valid json

```
print_r(json_decode($rawData));
```

Answer (score 1):

On your server php file , try that instead, and you get the parametes passed from client:

```
//get parameters 
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true); //read values from angular directive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

and do  `$data['jsonData']`
now this `$data['jsonData'] === $this->input->post('jsonData');`